# Integrate Prometheus scraping endpoint with ASP.NET Core pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, prometheus, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-middleware

We're trying to integrate the prometheus scrape endpoint with an existing ASP.NET Core site which hosts a Web API.

Here's how the middleware is configured (showing only the important part):

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
 
app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint( 
       predicate: ctx => ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Internally, `UseOpenTelemtryPrometheusScrappingEndpoint` ends up calling the `MapWhen` which uses the predicate to decide if the custom branch that returns the metrics should be following.

In this case, the web site is protected with bearer token generated by Azure AD. Prometheus has been configured to use OAuth2 and I can see that when it tries to access the metrics endpoint, it's able to get a valid access token which is mapped into a valid user (there's a transform call on the web site which maps the client id+secret into a special user).

Unfortunately, and even thought there's a "valid" user, the `ctx.User` property in the predicate is always "empty" (ex.: `IsAuthenticated` returns false always). I'm surely missing something, but what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, it ended up being a sum of several things. For starters, the token was being generated through OAuth2 client credentials flow (client id + secret).

When using this flow, the token does not contain scopes or tokens and authorization can be controlled through [access control lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Since we didn't have the `"AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": true` entry on the azure ad settings, the the token was [considered invalid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore).

After adding the entry to the settings, the library was able to validate the token against the ACL a it wasn't considered invalid anymore.

This was only an issue because a few days ago, the server side authentication/authorization code was updated to use `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` instead of the `AddJwtBearer` and this is when this feature (ACL use when having no tokens/roles) was enforced (previously, the token was considered valid when using the jwt bearer authentication/authorization library).